# Safety of candies with cat in house?

Tags: food-safety, candy, food-transport

I had several candies in individual plastic bags. I assembled paper bags to group together various candies to give to my classmates. I did this on a carpeted floor, with the plastic bags of candy over copy paper (occasionally touching carpet) and the paper bags that they would go into sitting directly on the carpet. I have a cat; cats step in their own litterboxes. The cat has not been in the house for a week. The candy itself, of course, has never touched anything but the hands of the woman who put them in the plastic bags.

Is there a risk if I give my classmates the candies?

Comment: If the candies are individually wrapped, the risk should be minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any risk with the candy itself, as you state that it is individually wrapped.  The only issue I see, and it is probably a fairly low risk issue, is if you have classmates who are severely allergic to cats.  I suppose there is potential for the bags to pick up some cat hair...but, now I am getting dangerously close to dealing with a health concern, which is off topic on our site.  So, my short answer is, for the individually wrapped candy...no significant risk.